# np.select join all true values together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe and would like to check for each row which of my conditions are true. If multiple are true I would like to return all of those choices with np.select. How can I do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cond1':[True, True, False, True],
                   'cond2':[False, False, True, True],
                   'cond3':[True, False, False, True],
                   'value': [1, 3, 3, 6]})

conditions = [df['cond1'] & (df['value']>4),
             df['cond2'],
             df['cond2'] & (df['value']>2),
             df['cond3'] & df['cond2']]

choices     = [ '1', '2', '3', '4']

df["class"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

I get this

```
   cond1    cond2   cond3   value   class
0   True    False   True    1       nan
1   True    False   False   3       nan
2   False   True    False   3       2
3   True    True    True    6       1
```

but would like to get this

```
   cond1    cond2   cond3   value   class
0   True    False   True    1       nan
1   True    False   False   3       nan
2   False   True    False   3       2 and 3
3   True    True    True    6       1 and 2 and 3 and 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this trick with [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(conditions, columns=df.index, index=choices).T
df['class'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + ' and ').str.strip(' and ')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   cond1  cond2  cond3  value                class
0   True  False   True      1                     
1   True  False  False      3                     
2  False   True  False      3              2 and 3
3   True   True   True      6  1 and 2 and 3 and 4
```

Intermediate result:

```
>>> df1
       1      2      3      4  <- columns from choices
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2  False   True   True  False
3   True   True   True   True
^- index from df.index
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I have created a check_conditions function which checks each condition individually for every row, appending the labels of the conditions that are met to a list. Then, it joins these labels with 'and' to represent the combined conditions in the "class" column. If no conditions are met, it assigns NaN.

Does this help?

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'cond1': [True, True, False, True],
                   'cond2': [False, False, True, True],
                   'cond3': [True, False, False, True],
                   'value': [1, 3, 3, 6]})

# Define a function to check conditions for each row
def check_conditions(row):
    # your conditions
    conditions = [
        (row['cond1'] and (row['value'] > 4)),
        row['cond2'],
        (row['cond2'] and (row['value'] > 2)),
        (row['cond3'] and row['cond2'])
    ]
    
    # your condition labels
    choices = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    
    # Check which conditions are met for the current row and store the corresponding choices
    conditions_met = [str(choice) for condition, choice in zip(conditions, choices) if condition]
    
    # Join the labels of met conditions using 'and', or assign NaN if no conditions are met
    return ' and '.join(conditions_met) if conditions_met else np.nan

# Apply the check_conditions function to each row of the DataFrame
df['class'] = df.apply(check_conditions, axis=1)
```